# How to configure IdentityServer in ASP.NET Core 3.1 production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, which works fine in development but in a production environment, I get the following error.

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
>
> InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions
> options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string
> name)
> ...

My `appsettings.json` contains

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "TestProjct": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
```

and `appsettings.Development.json` contains

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

I would like to configure the key for running in production but I'm unable to find documentation that states the different ways of configuring the key.

I've found [an example](https://newbedev.com/invalidoperationexception-key-type-not-specified-microsoft-aspnetcore-apiauthorization-identityserver-configuresigningcredentials-loadkey) that show using a .pfx file and the certificate store, but I would like to see everything that's available. Does anyone know where I can find documentation for this? Or could supply some additional examples of how to configure the key for production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asp.net core 3.1 not yet support import the key right from `.pem` file, then a `.pfx` file like your example link is a fair enough approach. I highly suggest you to generate yourself one, [openSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) is a widely used tool.

And Behind the screen, Identity server allow you to pass a security key in `.AddSigningCredential()`, which is exactly the thing `IdentityServer` yelling at you.

So another apprach would be generate a `RSA` or `ECDSA` key to pass them in. Something like:

```
// Generate the key programetically
using var keyProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
keyProvider.KeySize = 2048; // the default was 1024
var xmlKey = keyProvider.ToXmlString(true); // store the key as string somewhere

// Create the key and use it for jwt signing
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.FromXmlString(xmlKey);

// On your startup
services.AddIdentityServer()
    ...
    .AddSigningCredential(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa))
    ...;
```

You can obviously using other approach that generate a `pfx` file. But i personally prefer it over passing a key like this. At least the key could be generate using widely accepted tool if you choose the file approach.

Comment: I took your advice and created a pfx file with openssl. I'm being too stubborn looking for alternatives. Thank you for your answer. At the same time It would be nice to see documentation.

Comment: I'm not quite get it... the document on importing section or something ?

Comment: Documentation on how to configure IdentityServer in the appsettings.json file.

Comment: I think the official document of [Identity server](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html) would help, and if you aiming at deploying on the cloud then we must spend sometime search for implement each cloud provider key vault mechanism.